# Android system apps deleted, restore to default condition.

Tags: custom-roms, fm-radio, root-access

I have rooted my android phone and removed some of system apps form my Samsung GT-S5360 in order to save space. These are

- Email.apk
- EmailWidget.apk
- Memo.apk MyFiles.apk
- QuickOffice.apk
- SamsungApps.apk
- SamsungWidget_ProgramMonitor.apk
- SamsungWidget_StockClock.apk
- YouTube.apk

My phone is working very good except when I tried to play "FM Radio" which is not detecting any station at all.

Please tell me how to rest this phone to buy day condition. Or if replacing/flashing the firmware to S5360DDLK2_S5360ODDLK1 will solve my problem. Will change my IMIE etc?

Comment: Usual recommendation though too late in your case (remember for next time then): Don't ever go straight to delete, but first *freeze* (disable) apps to check for possible side effects. Had you done so, a simple "unfreeze" would have restored factory conditions without losing any data.

Answer (score 0):

First you should try to use the settings item "Reset Phone". 
 
You can find it at settings->back up and reset -> factory data reset.

*But remember: if you do this all your data will be deleted so do a backup on your pc or cloud first.*

- If this does not help try to find out your kernel and build and baseband. Normally Settings -> about phone.
- Load your firmware from [samfirmware](http://www.samfirmware.com/) and flash it with odin.
- There are several guides you can find (one is at samfirmware too).

Maybe there is a solution without resetting or flashing, but I don't know any. 
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to reflash ROM to restore to purchase day settings.
Since you deleted those .apk files, a simple reset won't do the trick.

IMEI is hard coded in phone, reflashing firmware will have no affect on that.

However, I don't see how any of the apps you listed as deleted should have anything to do with FM radio reception.... maybe the samsungapps has the programming to make radio work?